# PHP/Mysql receiving Undefined array key in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very simple php script that I am trying to run.   It ran previously on another portion of my project and worked beautifully.  I copied the snippet I needed to use for another section and even though the first previously run script still works the snippet copy refuses to work the same.  I searched here for the last 2 days and while there are "similar" posts, I couldn't find anything that helped in my current predicament which is odd or I am just super special :) I'm new here and this is my first question so If I did something wrong with it, I apologize.  I am just completely stumped as to how/why it's happening when it works perfectly in another spot.  Any help is appreciated.  If more information is needed just let me know.

**TestCode.php**

```
<?php
require_once("../data/config.php");
  
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * from groupleaders");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $row) {
    //I tried making variables but it kept telling me Undefined array key 
    $name = $row['name'];
    //after banging my head with the errors I commented all the variables out and did print_r($row); which returned everything as it should so I know the information is there.

}
?>
```

Comment: Try `var_dump($row)` to see what all it contains.

Comment: var_dump($row); gave me this but for every entry: 

{ ["LeaderID"]=> int(9) ["Name"]=> string(12) "Test Leader7" ["username"]=> string(8) "TLeader7" ["Email"]=> string(34) "testemail+testleader7@gmail.com" ["Phone"]=> string(12) "555-222-7783" } array(5)

Comment: Then use `$row['Name']`, array keys are case sensitive. P.S. You don't need to "make variables", where you assign stuff from an associative array into "$variables". This is perhaps one of the most redundant practices I see people doing. Just use the `$row['Name']` directly in your code. It's not like they need to be "downloaded" or something to become usable. :)

Comment: Thanks Markus, understood. I will try again!

Comment: Thanks again Markus,  it is working now.  I still used the variables because it's just easier for me and for this snippets purpose.